# Sequelize Model.bulkInsert does not return inserted values

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize migration script with this piece of code in it.

```
const [recipeCopies, ingredientCopies] = await Promise.all([
  queryInterface.bulkInsert('recipe', recipes, {
    returning: true,
  }),
  queryInterface.bulkInsert('ingredient', ingredients, {
    returning: true,
  }),
]);
console.log(recipeCopies);
```

The [documentation of `bulkInsert`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-bulkInsert) says that the [options of `bulkCreate`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-bulkCreate) apply. The option `returning` is documented as follows.

> If true, append RETURNING  to get back all defined values; if an array of column names, append RETURNING  to get back specific columns (Postgres only)

I'm passing true so I expect to get back all defined values. What I'm getting back instead and logged out is just "24", the first ID of the newly created entities.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using MySQL 5.7 and Sequelize 5.21.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in `Sequelize` documentation,
MySQL [does not support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) `RETURNING` for `INSERT` statements. It would work only for Postgres.

Comment: Thanks. I had related the "(Postgres only)" only to the part after the semicolon.